# What is the quickest way to dump a node to insert into a test case?

Tags: testing

Is there a script, console, drush command etc that can dump a node in the format needed to create a test case?

How can I rapidly fill out

```
$this->drupalCreateContentType(['type' => 'bond',
  'name' => 'Bond',
  'field_bond_amt_issued' => '1000000000',
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use drush:

```
drush ev "var_export(\Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load(123)->toArray());"
```

and delete stuff you don't need like uuid, revision_*, ...

By the way if you are wondering why does this output old style array syntax, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316347/how-to-format-var-export-to-php5-4-array-syntax

... or paste the output into your IDE and configure it to autocorrect the format.